# How to add query parameters while querying SOLR using solrpy (Like where clause in SQL)

Tags: python, solr

I'm very much new to SOLR. From my python app, I want to call SOLR. I'm using SOLRPY-python client to connect with SOLR. I want to search the SOLR document with some parameters. The following docs are generated for a RDBMS table.

```
<doc>
    <field name="appName">myapp</field>
    <field name="sno">6</field>
    <field name="subject">t1</field>
    <field name="predicate">DOMAIN</field>
    <field name="object">ITIS</field>
</doc>
<doc>
    <field name="appName">myapp</field>
    <field name="sno">7</field>
    <field name="subject">t1</field>
    <field name="predicate">SOLUTION</field>
    <field name="object">Please refer the below article</field>
</doc>
```

End user will give some text for querying the **object** field value, Once user sends the query, solrpy will call SOLR and gives the result. Here instead of searching all the SOLR docs, I want to search the SOLR docs which has **domain** value let say **ITIS**.

Application knows user is asking for a value which is from a particular domain alone. Hence If the search goes into all doc, for the user query it may gives the value from other domain also, which leads into unnecessary confusion on user's side

Like selecting a record in **RDBMS** using **where clause**,But domain is not a field here since it is not a column of a table for which SOLR index has done, however every object value will come under a domain value.

So, how can I add custom field in SOLR doc, though initially doc was generated for a particular table and that customized field was not part of it. Can I command the SOLR to narrow down the search. Any other SOLR python client also fine.Throw some lights on this please.

Comment: you should be able to do so by sending in the params (the relevant http request portion): fq=predicate:DOMAIN&fq=object:ITIS

Comment: @D_K If I do so, How I can get the solution predicate's object? Correct me if I'm wrong, I think, If I have an additional field in every doc to indicate the domain then I'll be able to, But I dont know whether it is fine to add?

Comment: do you need to access the solution's object in the same query with the domain's query object? If so you could use OR operator: fq=predicate:(DOMAIN OR SOLUTION)&fq=object:(ITIS OR article). To make things clearer, you could add a separate field for domain. Where will the value come from?

Comment: Yes I think the same, but the table which has used for this indexing doesn't contain domain column. Is it possible to add a field which is not part of the table?

Comment: You can configure this on the solr side in data-config.xml. There is an example configuration: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Full_Import_Example